# How to configure Ember routes in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ember.js, google-chrome-extension

We are developing a Chrome extension using Ember CLI, but are having difficulty getting the routes/resources to play nicely with Chrome as the *Index* route is not being fired correctly.

The steps we have taken:

- Create the default application using Ember CLI: `ember new myapp`.
- We do not define any routes as we should get the Index generated for us.
- Build: `ember build --environment production`.
- Put a *manifest.json* file to define the extension in the *dist/* folder.
- In Chrome we 'Load an unpacked extension...' and point it to the *dist/* folder.

Normally, if the Ember application was hosted on a server, going to where Ember serves the application, like *hxxp://localhost:4200/*, would load the application and all routes would hang off that.

However, as it's a Chrome extension, it doesn't load the *index.html* when using the empty route, such that going to *chrome-extension://(extension_id)/* gives an error *'This webpage is not found'* as I presume Chrome doesn't redirect to *index.html* by default.

If you point the extension to *chrome-extension://(extension_id)/**index.html*** it loads the Ember application, but then Ember gives an error:

> Uncaught UnrecognizedURLError: /index.html

One way around this is to define an `index.html` route in the router as below, but this isn't ideal:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('index', { path: '/index.html' });
});
```

Alternatively, you can change the location type to 'hash':

```
locationType: 'hash'
```

In this instance, it will allow going to index.html without the additional route above, but then how are routes able to hang off this? For example, going to *chrome-extension://(extension_id)/**some_other_action*** would never cause the Ember App to load in the first place.

**Question:** How can Ember routes be declared in a Chrome Extension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following these complete set of steps will allow you to build an application ready for Chrome with working routes:

**Create the default application using Ember CLI**

`ember new myapp`

**Update the config/environment.js file to include 'locationType: hash'**

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    ...
    locationType: 'hash',
    ...
  }
}
```

Now that 'hash' is used, it means you need to use the following pattern:

`chrome-extension://(extension_id)/index.html#/about?myparam={}`

**Put a manifest.json file to define the extension in the public/ folder**

Nothing special here

**Define a basic route**

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('about');
});
```

**Build application**

`ember build --environment production`

**In Chrome, 'Load an unpacked extension...' and point it to the dist/ folder**

Finally, point the browser to:

`chrome-extension://(extension_id)/index.html#/about`

Would like to thank Justin McNally and his [ember-cli-chrome](https://github.com/j-mcnally/ember-cli-chrome) source code for some pointers in getting the locationType set correctly.